# can't get data from api

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests

I am using api of a website to rent sms code, I used request library to send request to api. Initially I just printed out json to see what data I need, the results returned as below:

`{'status_code': 200, 'message': 'Tạo yêu cầu thành công !', 'success': True, 'data': {'phone_number': '587988009', 're_phone_number': '0587988009', 'countryISO': 'VN', 'countryCode': '84', 'request_id': 58266507, 'balance': 6400}}`

Yes, and the data name 'phone_number' is what I need. But when I try to get the phone number after the name, the error is returned:

`Exception has occurred: KeyError 'phone_number' File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microvirt\MEmu\final.py", line 58, in <module> number = data['phone_number']`

Here is my code:

```
import request

response = requests.get("https://api.viotp.com/request/getv2?token=my-apikey&serviceId=200")
data = response.json()['phone_number']
print(data)
```

Comment: The data you want is nested in another key "data" - `data = response.json()['data']['phone_number']`?

Comment: @IainShelvington Damnnn, so that's it! I'm a newbie so I don't quite understand, thanks u so much

Answer (score 0):

Following according below code:

```
import requests   
import json
response_API = 
requests.get('https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json')
#print(response_API.status_code)
data = response_API.text
parse_json = json.loads(data)
active_case = parse_json['Andaman and Nicobar Islands']['districtData']['South Andaman']['active']
```

print("Active cases in South Andaman:", active_case)

```
Output: Active cases in South Andaman: 19
```